# Is it ok two use two IDs for one Spring-Bean in a Spring-Config?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Suppose we have `Animal`-Beans and we want to define different concrete Animals like this:

```
public interface Animal
...
public class Cat implements Animal
...
public class Dog implements Animal
```

And we want to inject concrete Animals somewhere like

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("cat")
private Animal cat
```

Then we can define the Animal-Beans using IDs and @Qualifiers. So far so good.

*But* what if we were to identify the same Cat-Class with different IDs, like "cat" and "timmy" (the cat's name)? In other words we want a **surjective instead of a bijective mapping**.

Spring allows a configuration like this:

```
<bean id="cat" class="Cat"/>
<bean id="timmy" class="Cat"/>
```

Spring allows this and would give us a Cat-Class for both IDs (though not the same instance). Is this intended by design or am I misusing Spring, so that some day some future version of Spring won't support this behavior (two IDs for one Bean) anymore?

Comment: otherwise it wouldn't make any sense ...

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand, what is "otherwise" and why would't make it any sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right behaviour.

If you give explicitly a name to a bean a new bean with that qualifier is created.

This is useful and there is no reason to remove it.

Imagine for example what happens if you have an application that access to two different databases. You need two instances of Datasource. You can easily do that using a different id.

Comment: the bijective usage of two IDs to differ between two different databases is clear to me, but what if I use two IDs for the same database and another two IDs for the other database?

Comment: You will have two different DataSource objects pointing to the same database. In general two objects with two different ids can be equals using the equals method, but are differents using the == operator

Comment: yes this is what I want. Imagine a legacy-situation where you need to access the same DB using two different IDs and you cannot refactor everything, so that you could use only one ID. The question is: is it ok two use two IDs for one Bean in the spring-config?

Comment: You can use two id to identify two different o beans that can be possible equals by the equals method, but that are not equal for the == operator. Basically you can't have two different ids for the same object. But you can have for two identical objects.